# How to fix phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner on android

Tags: android, plugins, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner, phonegap

I am trying to use the Phonegap Barcode Scanner plugin on my app. When I view in Phonegap Desktop, the scanner doesn't display but I get an alert asking me to input the barcode number. However, when I package the app, submit to Phonegap Build and test on my phone, the barcode scanner/camera doesn't open and the alert doesn't appear.

I've installed android and browser as platforms to my project.

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
function (result) {
              alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                    "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                    "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                    "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
          },
          function (error) {
              alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
          }
);
```

Comment: Just to add, you can use the Phonegap app to instantly test on your Android device. Just search for "phonegap" in the Play Store

Answer (score 0):

Add permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```